# Django: no module named http_utils

Tags: python, django

I created a new `utils` package and an `http_utils` file with some decorators and HTTP utility functions in there. I imported them wherever I am using them and the IDE reports no errors, and I also added the `utils` module to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

However, when launching the server I am getting an import error:

> ImportError: No module named http_utils

What am I missing? What else do I need to do to register a new module?

Comment: create a package out of it and install it, that should work

Comment: how may I do that?

Comment: utils folder is having __init__.py file right?

Comment: Sure it does have it.

Comment: Are you calling it, from utils import http_utils.py

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/distributing/

Comment: @ArundasR well I am doing `from utils.http_utils import method_name`

Comment: can you post your directory tree?

Comment: @Divisadero I can't believe it should be that must be that much of a fuss to add a simple module. There must be a simpler way.

Comment: @arcegk it's just `app_name/mysite/utils`. There are dozens of other modules at the same level than `utls` and registered in `INSTALLED_APPS` the same way and they're working.

Comment: in how many files are you importing it?

Comment: @dabadaba Do you have a utils file in the app directory? If so rename that

Comment: @ArundasR no, as I said it's under `my_app/mysite`, like the rest of the modules

Comment: @arcegk I am importing it in just one so far. But I can import them in other files and the IDE reports no errors.

Comment: it seems to be a circular import

Comment: @arcegk No it is not. There is no import of itself in the `http_utils.py` file.

Comment: I mean in you are importing the file from views.py right? At the same directory level do you have a utils.py file? I had the same issue when I created utils folder now. When I changed the name of utils file it is fixed

Comment: @ArundasR Oh yes.... There's a `utils.py` file at the same level of the `views.py` file where I am importing it. What should I do?

Comment: Rename the file name. Or rename the folder name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the package is correct (Include **init**.py file).

Make sure there are no other utils files in the same directory level. That is if you are importing from utils import http_utils from views.py, there should not be a utils.py in the same folder. Conflict occurs because of that.

You dont have to include the folder in the INSTALLED_APP settings. Because the utils folder is a package and should be available for importing

Answer (score 0):

As stared by Arundas above, since there is a utils.py file I suggest renaming the module to something such as `utilities`, and also make sure you have a **__init__.py** file in that directory.

```
from utilities.http_utils import class_name
```

Comment: There was already an answer saying that, and the question was solved.